# is that + <subject> + <verb> OR is the + <noun>

Tags: phrasing

I am writing a paper and I want to criticize some other related work. I want to say that the problem of their work is that they don't support advanced composition rules. So which one is a better phrasing and why:

> The shortcoming of their approach is that they only support simple composition rules.

Or

> The shortcoming of their approach is the lack of support of advanced composition rules.

I will be grateful if you suggest a better phrasing.

Answer (score 2):

> The shortcoming of their approach is its lack of support for|of advanced composition rules.

sounds better to me (with the caveat that I have no idea what advanced composition rules are in this (unknown) context, and would be better able to respond if I did), but there's no one right answer to a question of this sort.

Comment: Why did you change `the` to `its`? I would imagine `its` here sounds like duplication, because we already mentioned `their approach` so `the lack` would by default be referring to `their support`.

Comment: I switched it simply because I thought it sounded better. It also clarifies whose lack it is: their approach's lack, or their own lack. (I trust I've chosen correctly?)

Answer (score 0):

Without more context it's hard to say, but I'd try something like the following:

> Their approach fails to support advanced composition rules.

We've done three things here:

1. We've pulled the most important part out, so that it's now the main clause.  In both of the original examples, the important part is buried in a subordinate clause or a prepositional phrase.
2. We've strengthened that clause by turning a wimpy negative ("lack of support"/"support only") into a positive statement ("fails to support").  We're saying what it *does* do.  "J'accuse!"
3. We've dropped the "shortcoming" bit entirely.  I'm taking a liberty here, but at this point, it seems redundant.  We've already characterized it as a failure.

Answer (score 0):

> The **shortcoming** of their approach is the **lack** of support of advanced composition rules.

The problem I see with this one is that it sounds too negative. Although it should be understood the way you want, the use of both **shortcoming** and **lack** seems redundant and unnecessarily critical. I would go with the first one:

> The shortcoming of their approach is that they only support simple composition rules.

I would even rephrase it to say:

> The shortcoming of their approach is that they do not support advanced composition rules.

Words like *only*, *shortcoming*, and *lack* have a more negative connotation than you really need, since you already said they have a shortcoming.